# Apache httpd virtual host is not accessible

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I am a newbie to linux, I was able to setup my LAMP server on Manjaro. Was getting the hang of everything but now having problems setting my virtual host. I am using httpd and commented out the **"Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"** in **/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**. But couldn't visit the host after editing the **httpd-vhosts.conf**. After searching through the web for solution, the latest I got was,

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin dummy@gmail.com 
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/sami" 
    ServerName dummy.local 
    ErrorLog "/srv/http/sami/dummy-host.example.com-error_log" 
    CustomLog "/srv/http/sami/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerAdmin dummy@gmail.com 
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http" 
    ServerName localhost 
    ErrorLog "/srv/http/error-log" 
    CustomLog "/srv/http/access-log" common 
</VirtualHost>
```

But dummy.local doesn't load and says,

> This site can’t be reached 
> dummy.local’s server IP address could not be found.

Thank you.

Comment: So you are going to dummy.local on your local web browser? To get to it on your local you should go to localhost on port 80. Your machine does not know what dummy.local is and can’t associate it with any ip. Hence is why you get the error that the IP address can’t be found.

Comment: @python-noob I saw some tutorials where people are using custom naming for individual projects other than localhost. That's what I was aiming for. Localhost works fine. But Alias or ServerName is not working for me.

Comment: Yep, so from your solution below, modifying your host file will make your local recognize the dummy.local and hence now it will associate it with whatever the ip you entered in the host file. You can associate your web server with a domain name by Pointing the Record of the domain name to your public ip of your web server. Then you can have a custom name (domain name) and you can get to it via going to the domain name vs using localhost or editing your host file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After troubleshooting some basics steps, I got around my problem by simply adding the **ServerName** of my virtual host to **/etc/hosts** as

> 127.0.0.1  dummy.local

That solved it for me. Hope this helps someone else as well. Have a good day.